# Unable to open excel spreadsheet in automation anywhere

Tags: automation, automationanywhere

I am using Automation Anywhere for inserting values into an excel file. I used thie below code for opening the spreadsheet.But the spreadsheet is opening in excel app instead of Microsoft Excel in my computer. I don't have the license for Outlook Excel App.

```
Excel: Open Spreadsheet "C:\Users\my_user\Documents\xyz.xlsx".ActiveSheet:"Default".Contains Header,Session:Default
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: If you double-click the xyz.xlsx file manually, how is it opened by default?

Comment: It is opening in normal Microsoft Excel not Excel App

Comment: Can you try opening the Excel file using the Open File command?

Comment: using a spreadsheet as a data store for your automation is generally an ant-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend:

- Open regedit -> navigate to
  `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\(your version
  here:probably 14.0)\options`
- From "File" create a new DWORD, call it
  `NoRereg`, and set its value to `1`
- After that - you'll need to go to the
  Programs and Features and repair Excel or the Office suite depending
  on how its installed
- Restart afterwards

If the above is not an option on your environment, you can always do:

- Launch Excel from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Excel.exe`
- Object Cloning-Set Text or keystrokes into Excel window to do `CTRL+O`
- Type in path name of file and press enter

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Create File "C:\Users\cxcioba\Desktop\Test.xls"
Excel: Open Spreadsheet "C:\Users\cxcioba\Desktop\Test.xls".ActiveSheet: "Default". Session: test
```

From your code I'd change to *.xls

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open in that way . go to c drive in your machine and look for the microsoft excel in the program files . you can use the same .exe in " Open program file " command